# I can't unpublish my Google play app. Unpublish button is not working for me

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I have an app in my google play console account. Now want **unpublished** from play console. From the console in advance setting I found an option called unpublished. but that option is not working. I can't click on that unpublish **radio** button. What can I do for that? I am attaching a snippet of that page.
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a programming question - it's about how google manage their store. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: You should contact Google Play support on this

Comment: I vote you quit passing judgement on a valid question. Google Play support will not help, All bots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the regular feedback Google gives you on what you need to have checked in order to be able to unpublish, one other key thing I found is that you need "Managed publishing" to be turned off. You can do that in the "Publishing overview" section.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Google Play is so painful. I appreciate the answer